# How would I create a billboard that is fixed to my camera's farplane?

Tags: unity, c#, billboarding

I'm trying to set a GameObject(plane) to be positioned at my camera's farplane. I plan on using this billboard as a sort of dynamic skybox. How would I create a billboard that is fixed to my camera's farplane?

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this in the shader:

```
Shader "Unlit/SkyplaneShader"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" "Queue"="Geometry+1"}
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = float4(v.uv * 2.0f - 1.0f, 0.9999f, 1.0f);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                // sample the texture
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

What this does is take a quad or and stretch it to fill the camera's viewport, at the furthest depth.

Note that this breaks Unity's expected bounds on the object - it's always in view, no matter whether Unity thinks the mesh is outside the camera frustum. I'd recommend either parenting it to the camera so they move together, or using a script to disable frustum culling on this object.

Answer (score 0):

First of all [Skybox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skybox_(video_games)) is not that sort of thing you are trying to create. It is a set of 6 images representing **up, down, left, right, top, bottom**. To understand it, make it simple, consider your camera is in a cube and your cube has definitely all 6 faces. For more details see [this link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Skybox.html).

Second *Plane* is quite expensive as compare to *Quad*, so if you want to use it in this way (anyway) then use Quad instead.

Third is I'd would suggest to use *Quad* on different layer rendering with a different camera, camera having depth less than your Main Camera and only rendering that *Quad*. From this easy step you will get your desired effect as your question is pretending.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more fitting to describe the sky box as 6 inner sides of a cube: front, back, left, right, top and bottom ?

Comment: He wants in that way, so... :)

Comment: Just thought I'd throw it out there for anyone learning about sky boxes. Point taken :)

Comment: Im brand new to unity and game design so sorry if this question seems stupid but if im constantly generating a texture on a plane at my cameras farplane will that mean I am avoiding the need for a skybox?

Comment: As far as I can understand what you have in your mind is a simple matte painting. And for that, my suggestion will work super duperly

Comment: Just like [in this game](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/zigzag-3d-runner/id1082647718?mt=8), I put another camera that is just rendering background elements, you can see that elements are not moving at all. That was the idea